# How to find a position of a character?

Tags: text-processing

I need to identify the postion of a character in string.

Example, the string is `RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333`.

```
grep -n '[^a-zA-Z0-9\$\~\%\#\^]'
```

How do I find the position of `|` in the given string?

Comment: it has to be with grep?

Comment: @Braiam I'm sure other solutions would be appreciated, like python, perl, etc.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `-b` to get the byte offset, which is the same as the position for simple text (but not for UTF-8 or similar).

```
$ echo "RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333" | grep -aob '|'
14:|
```

In the above, I use the `-a` switch to tell grep to use the input as text; necessary when operating on binary files, and the `-o` switch to only output the matching character(s).

If you only want the position, you can use grep to extract only the position:

```
$ echo "RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333" | grep -aob '|' | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
14
```

If you get weird output, check to see if grep has colors enabled. You can disable colors by passing `--colors=never` to grep, or by prefixing the grep command with a `\` (which will disable any aliases), e.g.:

```
$ echo "RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333" | grep -aob '|' --color=never | \grep -oE '^[0-9]+'
14
```

For a string that returns multiple matches, pipe through `head -n1` to get the first match.

Note that I use both in the above, and note that the latter will not work if grep is "aliased" through an executable (script or otherwise), only when using aliases.

Comment: Now search for `2` ;)

Comment: Thanks @Izkata, you're right. I've updated my post a tiny bit and added the missing hat `^` :)

Comment: Which version of grep did you use?  I get `0:|` as output-- because 0 is the byte position of the beginning of the line where `|` is found.

Comment: @Alex GNU grep from Debian stretch: `grep (GNU grep) 2.27`. Are you perhaps using OS X?

Comment: Can confirm - macos reports `0:|`

Answer (score 13):

If you're using the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell, you can use purely built-in operations without the need for spawning external processes such as [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ str="RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333"
$ tmp="${str%%|*}"
$ if [ "$tmp" != "$str" ]; then
> echo ${#tmp}
> fi
14
$
```

This uses a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove all occurrences of `|` follows by any string and save that in a temporary variable.  It is then just a matter of measuring the length of the temporary variable to get the index of `|`.

Note the `if` is checking if the `|` exists at all in the original string.  If it doesn't then the temporary variable will be the same as the orginal.

Note also this provides the zero-based index of `|` which is generally useful when indexing bash strings.  However if you require the one-based index, then you can do this:

```
$ echo $((${#tmp}+1))
15
$
```

Comment: probably the best answer, this syntax is beautiful and so fast and easy to use when you understand its meaning, long live to the core

Comment: It's also broken in the presence of special unescaped characters, which is usually why people start asking for 'positions of literal text' and not 'substrings'.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
printf '%s\n' 'RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333.' | grep -o . | grep -n '|'
```

output:

```
15:|
```

This will give you the position with index based-1.

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: @user82782: What command did you run? How you know it didn't work?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '|' | grep -o . | grep -n '|'` prints `1`, not `0` as expected.

Comment: @l0b0: The OP does not tell he wanted index base 0 or 1.

Comment: I just mean what a software developer would expect.

Comment: @l0b0 You can always pass it to the `$(( 'command' - 1))` to change it to index 0.

Answer (score 5):

You can use awk's `index` function to return the position in characters where the match occurs:

```
echo "RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333"|awk 'END{print index($0,"|")}'
15
```

If you don't mind using the Perl's `index` function, this handles reporting zero, one or more occurrences of a character:

```
echo "|abc|xyz|123456|zzz|" | \
perl -nle '$pos=-1;while (($off=index($_,"|",$pos))>=0) {print $off;$pos=$off+1}'
```

For readability, only, the pipeline has been split across two lines.

As long as the target character is found, `index` returns a positive value based at zero (0).  Hence, the string "abc|xyz|123456|zzz|" when parsed returns positions 0, 4, 8, 15 and 19.

Comment: for this use, awk is more usefull/easy than grep.

Comment: This only print the first position, won't work with string like `RAMSITALSKHMAN|1|223333`

Answer (score 3):

We can also do it using "expr match" or "expr index"

expr match $string $substring where $substring is a RE.

```
echo `expr match "RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333" '[A-Z]*.|'`
```

And above will give you the position because it returns the length of the substring matched.

But to be more specific for searching index :

```
mystring="RAMSITALSKHMAN|122333"
echo `expr index "$mystring" '|'`
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for commenting anywhere else. I personally liked answer given by @Gnouc . However why to  use awk and make it complex when we can do simple things using 'expr'

Comment: @kingsdeb it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @kingsdeb: Because (1) the `awk` solutions can trivially be modified for report this information on every line of a file (all you have to do is remove the `END`, which was never really necessary, from JRFerguson’s answer, and Avinash Raj’s does it already); whereas, to do that with the `expr` solution, you would need to add an explicit loop (and Gnouc’s answer is not easily adaptable to do that at all, that I can see), and (2) the `awk` solutions can be adapted to report all the matches in each line somewhat more easily than the `expr` solution (in fact, Avinash Raj’s does that already, too).

Comment: Why would you use `echo \`...\`` here?

Comment: This is to just show the output here

Answer (score 3):

[Another awk command](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Single-Character-Fields.html#Single-Character-Fields),

```
$ echo 'RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333'| awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "" }{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="|"){print i;}}}'
15
```

By setting the Field separator as null string, awk turns individual character in the record as separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

some alternatives include:

similar to Gnouc's answer, but with the shell:

```
echo 'RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333' |
tr -c \| \\n | 
sh

sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `|
sh: line 15: `|'
```

with `sed` and `dc` possibly spanning multiple lines:

```
echo 'RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333' |
sed 's/[^|]/1+/g;s/|/p/;1i0 1+' |dc

15
```

with `$IFS`...

```
IFS=\|; set -f; set -- ${0+RAMSITALSKHMAN|1223333}; echo $((${#1}+1))
```

That will also tell you how *many* there are like...

```
echo $(($#-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python answer

```py
text='skfwlefk|3oeio|ajda'
print([idx for idx, char in enumerate(text) if char == '|'])
# prints '[8, 14]'
```