# Finding string multiple positions in a large text file

Tags: grep, wc

I need to find the exact positions within the text of a certain string. i.e.
File:

```
to be or not to be, that's the question
```

String "to". Output needed: 0,14 (characters from the beginning until I find my sting). I tried:

```
$ grep -o 'to' myfile.txt | wc -l
```

this gives me "8597", ...I assume that this is the total number but I need the positions within the text, in characters.

Comment: does your file have multiple line or it is one line?

Comment: ... and if the latter, do you want the positions relative to the start of each line, or the  start of the file? and is it a string match or a word match (i.e. should `to` match in `potato` for example)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v str='to' '{ off=0; while (pos=index(substr($0,off+1),str)) { printf("%d: %d\n", NR, pos+off); off+=length(str)+pos } }' file
1: 1
1: 14
```

Or, more nicely formatted:

```
awk -v str='to' '
    {
        off = 0  # current offset in the line from whence we are searching
        while (pos = index(substr($0, off + 1), str)) {
            # pos is the position within the substring where the string was found
            printf("%d: %d\n", NR, pos + off)
            off += length(str) + pos
        }
    }' file
```

The `awk` program outputs the line number followed by the position of the string on that line.  If the string occurs multiple times on the line, multiple lines of output will be produced.

The program uses the `index()` function to find the string on the line, and if it's found, prints the position on the line where it is found.  It then repeats the process for the rest of the line (using the `substr()` function) until no more instances of the string can be found.

In the code, the `off` variable keeps track of the offset from the start of the line from which we need to do the next search.  The `pso` variable contains the position within the substring at offset `off` where the string was found.

The string is passed on the command line using `-v str='to'`.

Example:

```
$ cat file
To be, or not to be: that is the question:
Whether ‘tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them? To die: to sleep;
No more; and by a sleep to say we end
The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to, ‘tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wish’d. To die, to sleep;

$ awk -v str='the' '{ off=0; while (pos=index(substr($0,off+1), str)) { printf("%d: %d\n", NR, pos+off); off+=length(str)+pos} }' file
1: 30
2: 4
2: 26
5: 21
7: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep -b 'to' file
```

for offset from the beginning of the file;
or

```
grep -nb 'to' file
```

for line number and offset.

Answer (score 1):

if your file has multiple lines, to find the first occurrence of your string, you could use:

```
sed -zE 's/^(\w[^to]+)(to)(.*)/\1\2/' YourFile | wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to do this:

```
$ grep -aob 'to' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
0
13
```

Incidentally, your math appears off when you state you're looking for 0,14, the 2nd `to` starts at position 13 if you're counting 0 as the first, which you appear to be given your coordinates start with 0.

If you want the above output to be a comma separated list of coordinates:

```
$ grep -aob 'to' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | paste -s -d ','
0,13
```

#### How does it work?

This method exploits GNU `grep`'s ability to print the byte offset of matches (`-b`), and we're force it to only print these via the `-o` switch.

```
   -b, --byte-offset
          Print the 0-based byte offset within the input file before each
          line of output.  If -o (--only-matching) is specified, print the 
          offset of the matching part itself.
```

#### More advanced examples

If your example were to include words such as `toto` or were multi-lined this improved version of the above approach can handle these as well.

*Sample data*

```
$ cat file
to be or not to be, that's the question
that is the to to question
toto is a dog
```

*Example*

```
$ grep -aob '\bto\b' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | paste -s -d ','
0,13,52,55
```

Here we're using word boundaries `\b` on either side of the word we're counting to only count explicit occurrences of the string `to` and not words such as `toto`.

#### References

- [Format output of xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89130/format-output-of-xargs/89132#89132)
- [How to find a position of a character using grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153339/how-to-find-a-position-of-a-character-using-grep)

Comment: $ grep -aob 'to' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+'   worked perfectly!!! Thanks a lot Slm